# Installing ubuntu on my Laptop

Tags: system-installation

I am using a Sony Vaio SVE15113EN (E Series) laptop with i3-2370M CPU @2.40GHz (64bit processor) and 2 GB ram. I am also running win 7 pro. I am planning a dual boot. Could you please tell me which version of Ubuntu should I choose? All and any help would be most appreciated. Thank you in advance for your replies.

Comment: Take a look at [Windows Dual Boot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot).

Answer (score 0):

i use 13.04 64-bit since release on my desktop and laptop, i am satisfied with this version

or you can try 12.04 LTS 64-bit first and then upgrade if you think it is to buggy

Comment: Thank you Calin (if I may address you with that name) for your reply. I think I will try installing 13.04 64. Could you please tell me what all should I keep in mind while going ahead with this dual boot installation? I have no experience whatsoever in this, that's why.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS/Windows 7 dual-boot and it's running like a charm. What I would recommend is to backup your Windows files. Sometimes a dual-boot can be quite stubborn. Also check this: [WUBI-Installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer) Ohh and also this: [Dual-Boot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)